# In the field or on the field?

Tags: prepositions

I'm not sure I'm ready to get back **on/in** the field.

And field here means the speaker's line of work. 
What preposition do we use here **in** or **on**?
Are they interchangeable?

Comment: "the speaker's line of work" isn't clear. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure I'm ready to get back **on** the field.

Returning to the agricultural field (the land).

> I'm not sure I'm ready to get back **in** the field.

Returning to one's normal activities.

Comment: The first one, or a sports player.

Comment: I think that, for a farmer, _in the field_ works just fine.